# Bootstrap columns mess up upon resize

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a landing page and I made it using bootstrap columns, and this is how it look like fullscreen:[image: good]

And this is what it looks like when i try resizing it to half-screen:
[image: bad]

This is probably bootstrap trying to make the site mobile, is there a way to turn this off?

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title> title</title>
        <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
        <link href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>


    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-8 header">
                <div class="row title-row" >
                    <div class="col-md-1" >
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-3 left">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h1>A title</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>




body {
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url('img/bg6.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    background-color: #e1e1e1 !important;
}

.header {
    margin-top: 5vw;
    height:60vh;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.title-row {
    padding-top: 5vw;
}

.left {
    background-image: url(http://www.top13.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/blue-small-flower-555.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    height: 40vh;

}
```

Comment: Change from `col-md-` to `col-xs`, e.g. `col-xs-2`. This will keep the column widths. You can try using `col-sm` instead, if you want the elements placed differently on smallest screens, i.e. mobile devices

Comment: i suggest to read more about bootstrap and you will understand what is happening